# In HTML, how can I make a control take up all the horizontal space of its container without overlapping the border?

Tags: html, css

Consider this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<table cellspacing = "10" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input style="border-width:1px; border-style:solid; width:100%; background-color:aqua">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

It outputs the following, and, as you can see, there is a little bit of overlap on the right hand side.

[image: Output in IE and Chrome]

How can I change this code so that the input box will take up the entire inside space of the TD without overlapping?

Please note that I'm looking for a solution in which:

- The DOCTYPE tag and html tag are as mentioned above.
- The container elements' sizes are not fixed, as above.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no reason this needs to be a table.

Comment: You're missing HEAD tags and BODY and FORM tags in your HTML. This won't help matters. ALso as the other guy said this shouldn't be in a TABLE.

Comment: Try `box-sizing: border-box` on the `<input>`. More info [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html).

Comment: Does it matter if there aren't head nor body tags?  Doesn't seem to change the output if I put in head and body tags.

Comment: Yip, that works... thanks JamWaffles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding box-sizing: border-box on the input tag's style element solved the problem, as mentioned by JamWaffles.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing = "10" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input style="box-sizing: border-box; border-width:1px; border-style:solid; width:100%; background-color:aqua">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```